# Can One Say Y-A-H Before Doing Netilat Yadayim?

Tags: shemos-sacred-names

Is one allowed to proclaim the abbreviated form of the name of The Creator “יה” before doing netilat yadayim? Such as saying Hallelu-יה?

Comment: As opposed to other names?

Comment: Hi, this question - where is it coming from? Normally, you can't say Hashem's name for no reason - have you got a reason?